# Ordinary generating function of $n\cdot 2^{n-1}$ demonstration

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

How I could demonstrate that the ordinary generating function of $n\cdot 2^{n-1}$ is
$$\frac{x}{(1-2x)^2}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $a_n=n2^{n-1}$ and the way generating functions are defined, we have
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0} a_n\cdot x^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}n2^{n-1}\cdot x^n=\sum\limits_{n=1}n2^{n-1}\cdot x^n=x\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}n2^{n-1}\cdot x^{n-1}\right)=\\
x\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}n(2x)^{n-1}\right)=\frac{x}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}2n(2x)^{n-1}\right)=\frac{x}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}(2x)^{n}\right)'=\frac{x}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-2x}-1\right)'=\\
\frac{x}{2}\left(\frac{2x}{1-2x}\right)'=\frac{x}{2}\frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}=\frac{x}{(1-2x)^2}$$

Comment: Could you explain me this passage please? $\frac{x}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}2n(2x)^{n-1}\right)=\frac{x}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}(2x)^{n}\right)'$

Comment: That is derivative, term by term $((2x)^n)'=n(2x)^{n-1}(2x)'=2n(2x)^{n-1}$

Comment: not the 2nd derivative :) ... just re-applying the derivative.

Comment: ok so $(2x)'$ is the inverse derivative of 2? is correct?

Comment: inverse derivative of $2$ is $2x$ this is a much better way to put it.

Comment: Sorry last question: why the derivative is used? how did you know about this?

Comment: I just knew about it ... it's quite difficult to recall all the particular tricks and techniques I learned throughout the years. But I can recommend this link  http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=355

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the ordinary generating function of $2^n$?  What happens when you take a derivative?

Comment: the ordinary generating function of $2^n$ is $\frac{1-x}{1-2x}$ ?  but I do not know how to go on.

Comment: Well, $n = 0$ gives $1$, so you should just be getting $\frac{1}{1-2x} = 1 + 2x + 2^2 x^2 + \cdots$.  What happens if you differentiate both sides?